# Firefox memory leakage Tools

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox

I am working on very big application. And now facing lot of Javascript memory leakage in IE and Firefox. Chrome leakage we already fixed using Chrome Profiler, now Chrome doesn't show any leakage but IE and FF still shows lot of leakage. I have even tried IE11 Profiler (but it doesn't show reference of function responsible for leakage) and also tried `about:memory and about:ccdump` for Firefox, but nothing works.
Does anyone has any idea, how to fix memory Leakage in IE and Firefox? Or any tools over there for that... I am facing lot of problem with this issue.. Please help.

Comment: "Help me my program has bug, pls fix!"... Seriously? You need to give us some closer details what your "big application" is doing with the browsers and tell us some more helpful information and post some code where do you expect the memory leak to be. This way noone will really be able to help you

Comment: Its a big application with hundreds of JavaScript files, so I can't post code here.We can't go through all files and fix them manually.I just want to know are there any tools like Firefox Add-ons that can help to find out functions responsible for leakage.Something similar to Chrome Profiler but for Firefox and IE.My Application involves lot of JavaScript functionality.

Comment: Your entire application may have "hundreds of JavaScript files". But a single page would not normally have "hundreds of JavaScript files". So give more details about that single page. Or may be, you can point URL for that single page.